# predict function not working on R

Tags: linux, r, random-forest

I am creating a random forest in my local desktop and saving the model and loading in remote Linux machine. Following is the code chunk

```
iris.rf <- randomForest(species ~ ., data=iris, ntree=11)
save(iris.rf, file = "mymodel.rda")
```

On my Linux machine:

```
load(file="mymodel.rda")
out <- predict(iris.rf,data.frame(sepal_length=1,sepal_width=2,petal_length=3,petal_width=4))
```

When predicting getting the following error

> Error in UseMethod("predict") :
>     no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('randomForest.formula', 'randomForest')"

The random forest model has been loaded in the environment but for some reason the `predict` call on the model is not working. Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Did you also load the library `random.forest`?

Comment: I'll give you $1.01 odds that @Pascal has identified your problem.

Comment: I didn't load random.forest. But this is working in my local machine without loading random.forest for predicting(only predict based on the model in ,rda file). In the linux machine i can't install randomforest and hence saving the model in .rda file and loading it

Comment: @Naveenan - If `randomForest` isn't loaded, there will be no `predict` function loaded and available for `class(randomForest)` objects. No package, no prediction.

Comment: Are you sure your local machine doesn't have `randomForest` loaded? `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Thanks Pasacal, Alex and thelatemail for helping on this issue. I am trying to score a randomforest model through R streaming in hadoop. So I have to load randomforest on all the nodes. I will update once if figure out how to do it. Thanks